Does this relation between Wasserstein distances hold: $W_1(\mu,\nu)\leq W_2(\mu,\nu) \leq ... \leq W_\infty(\mu,\nu)$?
I stumbled upon this interesting statement in this paper:
"One interesting observation is that the Wasserstein ambiguity
set with the Wasserstein order p = 2 is less conservative, because the 2-Wasserstein
distance is stronger than 1-Wasserstein distance, i.e., $W_1(\mu,\nu) \leq W_2(\mu,\nu)$. Hence,
the 2-Wasserstein ambiguity set is smaller than the 1-Wasserstein ambiguity set,
which leads to less conservative costs."
Here $W_1(\mu,\nu)$ and $W_2(\mu,\nu)$ are the Wasserstein distances of order 1 and 2, respectively, between the distributions $\mu$ and $\nu$.
The Wasserstein distance is given by
$$W_p(\mu,\nu):= \inf \left\{\int_{\Xi^2}||\xi_1 - \xi_2||^p \Pi(d\xi_1,d\xi_2) \right\}^{\frac{1}{p}}$$,
where $\Pi$ is a joint distirbution of $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ with marginals $\mu$ and $\nu$, respectively.
Now to my question:
Does the following relation between the $p-$Wasserstein distance hold:
$$W_1(\mu,\nu)\leq W_2(\mu,\nu) \leq ... \leq W_\infty(\mu,\nu).$$
My initial thought is that it holds because of Jensen's inequality.

Villani, C. (2008). Optimal Transport: Old and New. Remark 6.6 says that this is a direct consequence of Holder

Great - thanks a lot :)
